# Prove two simple projection statements

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $U$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and suppose $v \in \mathbb C^n$.

Let p be the projection of the vector $v$ onto the subspace $U$. That is, p is defined as $P_U(v)$.

Prove :

(1) $\langle v,p\rangle = \langle p, p\rangle $

(2) $\|v\| = \|v-2p\| $

I tried to prove these statements using the projection properties but it didn't help me too much. I suppose I miss some basic steps in my proofs.

**To prove (1) I tried the following :**

> $\langle v,p\rangle = \langle P_U^\perp(v) + P_U(v), P_U(v)\rangle $

**To prove (2) I tried the following:**

> $\|v\| = \|P_U(v) + (v-P_U(v))\| $

That's as far as I could get.

Can anyone give an hint on how to prove these statements?

Comment: What is the scalar product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ you are using? EDIT: Do you mean by $C^n$ in fact $\mathbb C^n$? Then it's a different story.

Comment: The scalar product of the vector $v=(v_1,v_2,...,v_n)$ with the vector $u=(u_1,u_2,.....,u_n)$ is defined as $(v_1 \times u_1) + (v_2 \times u_2) + .... + (v_n \times u_n)$. I meant $\mathbb{C}^n$ of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove (1), we can use the linearity of the scalar product.
$$
\langle v,p\rangle = \langle P_U^\perp(v) + P_U(v), P_U(v)\rangle = 
\overbrace{\langle P_U^\perp(v), P_U(v)\rangle}^{0} + 
\langle P_U(v), P_U(v)\rangle
$$
To prove (2), note that $v = P_U(v) + P_U^\perp(v)$, so that we have
$$
\|v\|^2 = \|P_U(v) + P_U^\perp\|^2 = 
\langle P_U(v) + P_U^\perp(v), P_U(v) + P_U^\perp(v) \rangle
$$
Use the linearity of the scalar product, as before.  Moreover, we have
$$
v - 2p = (P_U(v) + P_U^\perp(v)) - 2P_U(v) = P_U^\perp(v) - P_U(v)
$$
apply the same expansion to $\|v - 2p\|^2$.

Comment: Seems very good. I'm thinking about it to make sure I understand it. Thank you!

Comment: I understood proof (1) . Regarding proof (2), If I expand the scalar product I get: $$ (P_U(v) \times P_U(v)) + (P_U(v) \times P_U^\perp(v)) + (P_U^\perp(v) \times P_U(v)) + (P_U^\perp(v) \times P_U^\perp(v)) $$  which equals to $$(P_U(v) \times P_U(v)) + (P_U^\perp(v) \times P_U^\perp(v)) $$ But why it equals to $$ \|v-2p\|$$  ?

Comment: Note that $v - 2p = P_U^\perp(v) - P_U(v)$. Do the same expansion.  Also, remember: $\langle P_U(v) , P_U^\perp(v) \rangle = 0$, by the definition of orthogonality.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I'm trying to see how it helps me.

Comment: That square root shouldn't be there.  Otherwise, guess it's fine?

Comment: You are correct. I removed my last comment and wrote it again : $$\|v-2p\|^2 = \langle  (P_U^\perp(v) - P_U(v)), (P_U^\perp(v) - P_U(v)) \rangle $$ And , $$ \|v\|^2 = \langle (P_U(v) + P_U^\perp(v)), (P_U(v) + P_U^\perp(v)) $$ And both are equal. I understood. Thank you very much again :)

Answer (score 1):

(1) As elements of $U$ and $U^\perp$ are orthogonal, it follows
$$
\langle v,p\rangle = \langle P_{U^\perp}(v) + P_{U}(v), P_U(v)\rangle =\langle P_{U}(v), P_U(v)\rangle = \langle p,p\rangle.
$$
Orthogonal projection splits the vector $v$ uniquely into $p = P_U(v)\in U$ and $v-p=P_{U^\perp}(v)\in U^\perp$. Since vectors from $U$ are orthogonal to vectors from $U^\perp$, one obtains $\langle P_{U^\perp}(v), P_U(v)\rangle=0$.

(2) You can prove $\|v\|^2 = \|v-2p\|^2$ using (1) - just compute all the arising scalar products.